# Multiple checkbox values into hidden field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a couple checkboxes, on clicking each I would like their value to go into a hidden field with jQuery seperated by commas, if they are all unchecked, the hidden field value would go back to -1. Below is what I have tried.

```
<input type="hidden" name="agreement_ids" value="-1">

<input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-1" name="agreeCheck-1" value="35" class="mandatory agreeChecker">
<input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-2" name="agreeCheck-2" value="45" class="mandatory agreeChecker">
<input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-3" name="agreeCheck-3" value="52" class="mandatory agreeChecker">

$('.agreeChecker').click(function(){

        if($(this).prop('checked')){

            var resultObj = $(this).val();
            var outputObj = $('input[name="agreement_ids"]');
            var stringToAppend = resultObj.val().length > 0 ? resultObj.val() + "," : "";
        resultObj .val( stringToAppend + outputObj.val() );

        }else{
            if($('.agreement-text').length > 0){
                $('input[name="agreement_ids"]').val('-1');//uncheck
            }else{
                $('input[name="agreement_ids"]').val('');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What happens, or doesn't happen? Are there errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a wrong approach to build comma separated values. with your code, its difficult to find out whether checked element value is already appended in hidden field or not.

I'd suggest you to modify click handler to,

1) Get all checked element first

2) join their values to create CSV using `.map()` function

3) if length of checked element in step 1 is 0, set -1 else set joined value from step 2 above

```
$('.agreeChecker').click(function(){
  var $checkedagreeChecker = $('.agreeChecker:checked');
  var joinedValues = $checkedagreeChecker.map(function(){return this.value}).get().join(",");
  $('input[name="agreement_ids"]').val($checkedagreeChecker.length > 0 ? joinedValues : -1 )
});
```

Comment: So what was the problem with the OP's posted code? Without explaining the mistake(s) you're providing, at best, half an answer.

Comment: Beautiful and simple.

Answer (score 0):

i have updated your code can you please verify

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".agreeChecker").click(function () {
            var checked_checkboxes = $('#aggrement input[name="agreeCheck"]:checked');
            var message = "";
            var chkCount = 1;
            checked_checkboxes.each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var inputObj = $(this)[0];
                if (inputObj.checked) {
                    if (chkCount == 1)
                        message += value;
                    else
                        message += "," + value;
                    chkCount++;
                }
            });
             if (message == "")
                $("#agrrementID").val("-1");
            else
                $("#agrrementID").val(message);
            console.log($("#agrrementID").val());
        });
    });

 <div id="aggrement">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-1" name="agreeCheck" value="35" class="mandatory agreeChecker">35</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-2" name="agreeCheck" value="45" class="mandatory agreeChecker">45</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-3" name="agreeCheck" value="52" class="mandatory agreeChecker">52</label>

    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="agreement_ids" id="agrrementID" value="-1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with logic of your J query code please check below code

```
 $('.agreeChecker').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            var resultObj = $(this).val();
            var outputObj = $('input[name="agreement_ids"]');
            var stringToAppend = resultObj.length > 0 ? resultObj + "," : "";
            if (outputObj.val() === '-1') {
                $('input[name="agreement_ids"]').val('');
            }
            outputObj.val(stringToAppend + outputObj.val());
        } else {
            if ($('.agreement-text').length > 0) {                   
                $('input[name="agreement_ids"]').val('-1');//uncheck
            } else
            {
                $('input[name="agreement_ids"]').prop("value", "-1");                  
            }
        }
    });
```

I try to put some conditions in code working fine hopefully may it help you

Thanks